# How to remove prefix of some column names(not all) in the data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame with column names contain prefix "ATH_".
I would like to remove the prefix(ATH_) from 2 columns(ATH_V1 and ATH_V6) only and keep the other as it. I would apricate it if some could show me how to do it

here is the data

```
df = data.frame(ATH_V1 = rnorm(10),ATH_V2 = rnorm(10), ATH_V3 = rnorm(10), ATH_V4 = rnorm(10), ATH_V5 = rnorm(10), ATH_V6 = rnorm(10), ATH_V7 = rnorm(10))
```

best
Amare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(ATH_V1 = rnorm(10), ATH_V2 = rnorm(10), ATH_V3 = rnorm(10), ATH_V4 = rnorm(10), ATH_V5 = rnorm(10), ATH_V6 = rnorm(10), ATH_V7 = rnorm(10))

df %>% rename_at(c("ATH_V1", "ATH_V6"), ~ .x %>% str_remove("^ATH_"))
#>            V1      ATH_V2     ATH_V3     ATH_V4     ATH_V5         V6
#> 1  -0.9787741  0.59753561  1.4606176 -0.7222365  1.1619974  1.4245440
#> 2  -0.1422491 -0.04015642  1.5231930 -0.2215489  0.4733293 -1.1778313
#> 3   1.4313557  2.00300580  0.4363795 -0.3052510 -0.6962659  1.2960786
#> 4  -0.1911366  2.11970596  1.9875712  0.6113360 -1.2350625  0.2592453
#> 5  -0.5302929 -1.12845335  1.5572375  0.7197645  2.3677693  0.4524042
#> 6   0.2509259 -0.72251478 -1.0877208 -0.8178679  1.2782181  0.5684512
#> 7  -1.2612433  0.47157422 -1.0725161  0.9568031  1.0750650 -0.1186985
#> 8   0.1603012 -1.44786690  1.4712967  0.3131179 -0.2008229  1.8550673
#> 9  -0.4151117 -0.21775032 -0.6140963 -1.3066199 -0.6131560  0.4374292
#> 10  0.4018190  0.86672247 -0.6959701 -0.2791933 -0.7067717  0.5536431
#>          ATH_V7
#> 1  -0.363026020
#> 2  -0.009262505
#> 3   0.918104560
#> 4   0.412474155
#> 5   0.995838735
#> 6  -1.594121815
#> 7  -0.337275182
#> 8  -0.103933907
#> 9  -2.081604720
#> 10 -0.485858946
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

And this is the untidy base R way:

```r
df <- data.frame(ATH_V1 = rnorm(10), ATH_V2 = rnorm(10), ATH_V3 = rnorm(10), ATH_V4 = rnorm(10), ATH_V5 = rnorm(10), ATH_V6 = rnorm(10), ATH_V7 = rnorm(10))


colnames(df) <- gsub("ATH_V1", "V1", colnames(df))
colnames(df) <- gsub("ATH_V6", "V6", colnames(df))
df
#>             V1      ATH_V2      ATH_V3       ATH_V4     ATH_V5          V6
#> 1  -0.35552493 -0.37204277 -0.08444175  1.130647161  1.1661803  0.27236180
#> 2  -0.07985964 -0.08258812  1.06567654  1.902107885  0.3968539  0.61982182
#> 3  -0.62163060  0.27027080 -0.21261031 -1.350332160  0.3457151 -0.07860671
#> 4   0.83802149 -0.68230936 -0.70406713 -1.419061955 -0.9219630 -0.22298239
#> 5   0.26523276 -0.51319596  0.52479582 -0.296881967 -0.5851320 -0.37569453
#> 6   0.05813191 -0.14596572  0.89145489  0.009077575  1.3361470 -1.05678268
#> 7  -1.27938803  0.42779751  1.60554767 -0.987068721 -0.9159335 -1.20812957
#> 8  -1.11941600 -0.18524402 -0.34429496  1.359745919 -0.2284247 -2.23770593
#> 9  -0.85515966 -1.60610739 -0.10625336  1.502378126  0.5116960 -0.39652781
#> 10  0.59169485  0.63978346  0.24746627  0.542039986  0.3506836  0.55661274
#>        ATH_V7
#> 1  -1.1306128
#> 2   0.5123795
#> 3   0.7520832
#> 4  -0.4624818
#> 5   1.6806410
#> 6   0.5525226
#> 7  -0.1802064
#> 8   0.6647524
#> 9   0.2381197
#> 10  1.4689589
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: is there a non tidyverse way of doing the same?

Comment: I added the untidy way ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use -

```
cols <- c('ATH_V1', 'ATH_V6')
names(df)[names(df) %in% cols] <- sub('ATH_', '', cols)
#Or remove any prefix. 
#names(df)[names(df) %in% cols] <- sub('.*_', '', cols)
names(df)
#[1] "V1"  "ATH_V2" "ATH_V3" "ATH_V4" "ATH_V5" "V6"   "ATH_V7"
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use `trimws` in `base R`

```
nm1 <- sprintf("ATH_V%d", c(1, 6))
names(df)[match(nm1, names(df))] <- trimws(nm1, whitespace = ".*_")
```

-output

```
names(df)
[1] "V1"     "ATH_V2" "ATH_V3" "ATH_V4" "ATH_V5" "V6"     "ATH_V7"
```